KDE Plasma Setting: Only raise the single window I click on
Let's say I've got three applications open in KDE Plasma 5; Dolphin, Konqueror, and Konsole. I can minimize all three applications by pressing Super+d. Once all windows are minimized I often want to raise a single application, say Konsole. I click on Konsole in the taskbar and KDE raises all three previously activated windows (Dolphin, Konqueror, and Konsole). How do I disable this behavior of raising every active Window after a Super+d invocation. I only want to raise the one window I click on. Is there a setting? xdotool to the rescue?

There's a Minimize All Windows widget that's located at the far right of the KDE Plasma taskbar. You can right click on that and select Configure Minimize All Windows, then click on Shortcut and press Meta+d (ie Super+d) as the shortcut. A prompt will appear asking if you want to reassign Super+d from Peek at Desktop to Minimize All Windows. Select Reassign and you're done.
